# i want to select file from CKeditor from browse server button

Tags: ckeditor

I have browae server button

I am working in asp.net c#.

I want to select image from my imagefolder

it means when i click on Browse Server button, my imagefolder must open and when i click any of the image. it must be selected and selected image path mustbe copied on url textbox..

regards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, basically you need two things:

1. make sure that the *filebrowser* plugin is available in your CKEditor package - this plugin makes it possible to attach external file managers to CKEditor
2. ...and you need some file manager.

There is an official ajax file manager for CKEditor created by CKSource and it is called [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder). If you decide to give it a try make sure to check [the documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET)